# Call undo when click my custom button in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How to run undo function after click my custom button in tinymce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run undo function :
`editor.undoManager.undo();`

Comment: thanks.. it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Type This Code

```js
function updateButtons(history) {
 $('#undo').attr('disabled',!history.canUndo());
}
function setEditorContents(contents) {$('#editor').val(contents);}
$(function(){
 var history = new SimpleUndo({
  maxLength: 200,
  provider: function(done) {
   done($('#editor').val());
  },
  onUpdate: function() {
   //onUpdate is called in constructor, making history undefined
   if (!history) return; 
   
   updateButtons(history);
  }
 });
 $('#undo').click(function() {
  history.undo(setEditorContents);
 });
 $('#editor').keypress(function() {
  history.save();
 });
 updateButtons(history);
    });
```